# Bibtex "I couldn't open file name 'article.tex' "

Tags: bibtex

I have tried getting bibtex to work using the 
latex filename
bibtex filename
latex filename
latx filename 
commands
I DID NOT USE bibtex mybib
and I still get the error "I couldn't open file name 'blabla'"
Numerous people have posted a similar problem, but I cannot find a single answer that actually addresses the error, instead of just pointing out that bibtex filename should be used and not bibtex mybib.
[image]

Does anybody know a real solution to my problem?
Please...I have been searching the internet for over an hour.

I would like to point out that I usually use Latexila, and I tried the command prompt after Latexila failed to compile bibtex. The error messages were essentially the same in Latexila as the command prompt. 
[image]

I also tried putting the tex file name into the /bibliography{filename} command:
[image]

I have also tried a long list of other variations, that would take pages to list and describe here...nothing works.

Comment: What operating sysstem? What IDE (TexMaker, kile,et c)? What distribution of LaTeX (Miktex, TexLIve or other)?  But without any extra information, I suspect you have a path problem.

Comment: It looks (reading between the lines) that your file is called `article.tex` and you used the command `bibtex article.tex` which would be wrong. the command should be `bibtex article`

Comment: I also tried compiling using the Latexila interface and got the same error.

Comment: I am working in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I typed exactly what the error messages said, but I do not know how to added the actual text to the forum post.

Comment: Ok I included a screen shot, but I don't see how that provides any additional information.

Comment: Your current directory is not the same as the location of your *.tex file.  Do an appropriate change directory so that you run bibtex from the same directory as the *.tex file.  Also the *.bib file must be in the same directory .   Now the *.aux file will be in that same folder.   Right now you are trying to run Bibtex for a directory that you do not have permission to save in.

Comment: David Carlisle are you actually trying to help me or just convince yourself you are superior because my problem is still unresolved and this forum is not helping.

Comment: the name of the bibtex file is References.bib

Comment: the name of the latex file is Chem294_ProjectIdea2_16_March_15.tex

Comment: then cd to the directory that has your tex file and References.bib and use `latex Chem294_ProjectIdea2_16_March_15; bibtex Chem294_ProjectIdea2_16_March_15; latex Chem294_ProjectIdea2_16_March_15`

Comment: they are both together in the folder "Articles_For_Idea2_Methane" in my documents folder.

Comment: I tried that, it's in my response to the answer, that didn't work.

Comment: and even if that is the problem, why does it not work in the latexila interface. I don't think it is related to a command error.

Comment: What do you mean by "have \bibliography{References} in the file"? Did you see the two added screenshots?

Comment: But I can see it in the folder, I can open it as a text file

Comment: which terminal output do you want? I have tried so many different things at this point, I am losing track, but every single one gives me some sort of error.

Comment: @PandaLogique Please visit us in the [chat]. David and you could speak a bit about details so this question could be clarified. Building up such an amount of comments isn't so helpful and hard to follow for others. 1. Move the talk to the chat. 2. Edit question and add necessary information, as clarified in the chat then. Comments can be removed, all info should go to the question. 3. Problem can then be solved here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22010/discussion-on-question-by-panda-logique-bibtex-i-couldnt-open-file-name-artic).

Answer (score 1):

The input file for the command `bibtex` is the `.aux` file. The extension is optional. If the specified file name does not end in `.aux`, then the extension is appended. The specified file name in the screen shot ends in `.tex`, thus
`bibtex` has added `.aux` and the resulted file name does not exist. Solution:
Just omit the extension `.tex`, then `bibtex` finds the auxiliary file name, written by the LaTeX run.

The next issue is the bibliography database:

The LaTeX run writes the argument of `\bibliography{...}` into the `.aux` file as `\bibdata{...}`. Then `bibtex` adds the extension `.bib` and wants to read the file. Usually the file does not contain an absolute path name, often the `.bib` file is in the same directory as the `.tex` file. Then `bibtex` will fail to find the `.bib` file, if the current directory is different.

Therefore I would first go to the directory with the `.tex`, `.aux` and `.bib` files:

```
cd /home/ninja/Documents/294/Articles_For_Idea2_Methane
```

Then the `bibtex` command becomes:

```
bibtex 'Chem294_ProjectIdea(2)_16_March_15'
```

or

```
bibtex 'Chem294_ProjectIdea(2)_16_March_15.aux'
```

Comment: This does not work. I get the same errors for both attempts

Comment: I have tried this and I get: "bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('" when I do not use the file directory with the bibtex command. I tried renaming my tex file with the () removed from around the 2. I started over with "latex Chem294_ProjectIdea2_16_March_15" Now it says "! I can't find file Chem294_ProjectIdea2_16_March_15"

Comment: This still does not work for me I got the same errors working in the directory as noted in my above comment

Comment: @PandaLogique The answer contains single quotes (linux) because of the parentheses inside the file name. The file name should work with the correct quoting. Of course, simplifying the file name is also not a bad idea. The "file not found error" is probably based on a spelling error. The command `ls` for a directory listing or the file name completion feature of `bash` can help to find the correct file name.